# MongoDB: How to get distinct list of sub-document field values?

Tags: mongodb, distinct, nosql

Let's say I have the following documents in collection:

```
{
   "family": "Smith",
   "children": [
        {
            "child_name": "John"
        },
        {
            "child_name": "Anna"
        },
    ]
}

{
   "family": "Williams",
   "children": [
        {
            "child_name": "Anna"
        },
        {
            "child_name": "Kevin"
        },
    ]
}
```

Now I want to get somehow the following list of unique child names cross all families:

```
[ "John", "Anna", "Kevin" ]
```

Structure of result might be different. How to achieve that in MongoDB? Should be something simple but I can't figure out. I tried aggregate() function on collection but then I don't know how to apply distinct() function.

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can just do:

```
db.collection.distinct("children.child_name");
```

In your case it returns:

```
[ "John", "Anna", "Kevin" ]
```

Comment: Damn, so easy! I cracked my head. Thanks this is shortest working answer, giving me exactly what I want.

Comment: ok - but what about performance on sharding cluster? distinct will be processed on each rs instance for example ;)

Comment: Obviously I'm not at that point thinking of performance yet. But this is significant thing, thanks.

Comment: if you have a sharded cluster everything you have to do across the full data set will be processed on each shard "for example" and then merged by mongos.  that's how sharding works.  And note "distinct" will try to use indexes whenever possible.

Comment: OK, since this discussion started. Here's a question for experts regarding distributed storage. I'm thinking of distributed storage because I expect to have billions of parent documents (families in my example) and each document will have average 30 subdocuments (children). Operations which I need to do often: get unique children names, get all families having kid with specific name. What features of Mongo should I consider first?

Comment: that's too open-ended of a question for this forum.  I suggest asking this on the Google group mongodb-users.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky how can we achieve that in MongoDB Compass

Answer (score 6):

with the help aggregation framework:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$unwind:'$children'}, {$group:{_id:'$children.child_name'}}])
```

or more interest ;) with frequency of name:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$unwind:'$children'}, {$group:{_id:'$children.child_name', freq:{$sum:1}}}])
```

Comment: but that's not what he asked for - he wants distinct names array not subdocuments with each name and its count...

Comment: i read it:

> "Structure of result might be different."

and yes!, this is a different structure ;)

Comment: Yes, thanks. It works, and forces me to learn more about aggregate()

Comment: aggregation framework is powerfull tools ;) 
and in this case you can calculate some statistics about names

Comment: if you want to use aggregation framework why not just do {$group:{_id:1, children:{$addToSet:"$children.child_name"}}} then?  that gives you one result back with array of names in "children" field.