# Getting distinct value of the _id field in mongo db

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection which is the result of a map_reduce that looks like this.

```
[
  {
    _id: { id_field1: 'id_field_value1', ... }
    value: { value_field1: 'value_field_1' }
  },
  ...     
]
```

Now I want to get the distinct values of _id.field1
But

```
collection.distinct('_id.id_field1')
```

returns an empty list.

If I do

```
collection.distinct('value.value_field1')
```

I get the expected results. (As point out here : [MongoDB: How to get distinct list of sub-document field values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155266/mongodb-how-to-get-distinct-list-of-sub-document-field-values))

Is there any reason why I can't distinct values from the id of the document?

EDIT:
mongo 2.5.5
actual document

```
 db.collection.findOne()

 { _id : { year : 2013, month : 11, date : 2, language : en-US},
   value : { sentence_eval : { Num : 36, PerfectMatch : 33} }
 }
db.collection.distinct('value.sentence_eval.Num)
[36,...]
db.collection.distinct('_id.language')
[]
```

Comment: That's very strange. What version of MongoDB? I just tested with 2.4.8 by inserting a few documents with a structure similar to what you show, and `distinct` worked as expected and returned the distinct values for `id_field1`. Could you edit the question to include a single document: `db.collection.find().limit(1);`

Comment: Are you using the MongoDB console? there's not a `find_one` function. There's a `findOne`. I'm not using the beta version of MongoDB as I mentioned, but .... try: `db.collection.aggregate({$group : { _id: "$_id.language" }})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 2.5.5 of mongodb seems to have the bug.
I verify with 2.4.9 and 2.6RC1 and it is now working as intended. So updating mongodb fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same query with the same collection that you have and distinct() does return the expected value.  Please see below.

BTW, the value for _id.language has to be enclosed within double-quotes. I hope what you entered is a typo.

```
> db.bar.findOne()
{
        "_id" : {
                "year" : 2013,
                "month" : 11,
                "date" : 2,
                "language" : "en-US"
        },
        "value" : {
                "sentence_eval" : {
                        "Num" : 36,
                        "PerfectMatch" : 33
                }
        }
}
> db.bar.distinct("value.sentence_eval.Num")
[ 36 ]
> db.bar.distinct("value.sentence_eval.PerfectMatch")
[ 33 ]
> db.bar.distinct("_id.year")
[ 2013 ]
> db.bar.distinct("_id.language")
[ "en-US" ]
```

Comment: I said the same in my comments that `distinct` worked as expected.

Comment: I switch to mongo 2.4.9 (brew switch mongodb 2.4.9) and now it is working. So I guess that is a bug in the latest version.

Comment: If you're going to use a non-production version, I'd suggest 2.6RC1.

Comment: Updated to 2.6RC1 and the bug is gone.