# python mongodb distinct key return whole sub document

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a further question based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155266/mongodb-how-to-get-distinct-list-of-sub-document-field-values),

```
{
   "family": "Smith",
   "children": [
        {
            "child_name": "John",
            "age":5
        },
        {
            "child_name": "Anna",
            "age":6
        },
    ]
}

{
   "family": "Williams",
   "children": [
        {
            "child_name": "Anna",
            "age":6
        },
        {
            "child_name": "Kevin",
            "age":7
        },
    ]
}
```

As the highest voted answer shows, I can get the distinct child name by the following code,

```
  db.collection.distinct("children.child_name");
```

My question is how can I get the whole sub document for each distinct child name?

That means I would like to have returned a list of sub-document based on unique child name,

```
[ {"child_name":"John", "age":5}, {"child_name": "Anna","age":6}, {"child_name":"Kevin","age":7}]
```

Comment: The second answer will cover that, use `$first` or `$last` to return the age within the `$group` pipeline i.e. `db.collection.aggregate([{$unwind:'$children'}, {$group:{_id:'$children.child_name', age:{$first: '$age'}}}])`

Comment: Which one do you keep if you have two or more embedded documents with same name `{"child_name": "Anna","age":6} and {"child_name": "Anna","age":7}`  ?